# Using a CustomRequest for Form Validation in Laravel 5.1 fails?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I've created a custom `Request` called `CustomerRequest` that I want to use to validate the form fields when a new customer is created. I cannot get it to work, it appears to be continuing into the `store()` method even when it should fail.

I have three required fields: givenname, surname, email

Here is my `CustomerRequest`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'givenname' => 'required|max:3',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:customers,email',
    ];
}
```

Here is my `CustomerController`:

```
use pams\Http\Requests\CustomerRequest;

-----------------------------------------

public function store(CustomerRequest $request, Customer $customer)
{
    $request['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $request['modified_by'] = Auth::user()->id;

    $customer->create($request->all());

    return redirect('customers');
}
```

When I submit the form using a `givenname` of "Vince" it should fail because it is greater than 3 characters long, but instead I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in CustomerController.php line 52: Cannot use object of type pams\Http\Requests\CustomerRequest as array
```

Line 52 in the controller is `$request['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;`

From what I understand, if the `CustomerRequest` fails then the user should be redirected back to the `customers.create` page and not run the code contained in the `store()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

`CustomerRequest` had:

```
use Request;
```

instead of:

```
use pams\Http\Requests\Request;
```

Now the validation passes and fails as expected.

Comment: when you make a new request using `php artisan make:request` it creates the file for you and it has `use pams\Http\Requests\Request;` at the top.

Comment: Yes, I know! so you can make your validation on inputs, but you are not returning it in your `rules()` method so it's a different story

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation), in **Form Request Validation**:

> All you need to do is type-hint the request on your controller method.
>   The incoming form request is validated before the controller method is
>   called, meaning you do not need to clutter your controller with any
>   validation logic

**Solution** would be if you use it like so:

`CustomerController.php`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// ...
public function store(CustomerRequest $customerRequest, Customer $customer,Request $request)
{
    $request['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $request['modified_by'] = Auth::user()->id;

    $customer->create($request->all());

    return redirect('customers');
}
```

---

So what you want to know is that FormRequest -- which you are extending in your custom request validator `CustomerRequest.php` -- is a bit different than `request` that resides in `Illuminate\Http` namespace. 
actually, you may find out why if you run (with your old code) `dd($request['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id);`. you should get the word **forbidden** or *maybe!* an exception telling that it'is not instantiable. *(in my case I got forbidden because I've tested it on 5.2 right now).*

Answer (score 0):

$request is object, use it like following

```
use pams\Http\Requests\CustomerRequest;

-----------------------------------------

public function store(CustomerRequest $request, Customer $customer)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $inputs['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $inputs['modified_by'] = Auth::user()->id;

    $customer->create($inputs);

    return redirect('customers');
}
```